# H14 error upon Django app deployment on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I tried today to deploy my Django app on Heroku.
I first had success and got the message that it is deployed. However upon Heroku open I had a screen informing me that an error occurred and that I should check the logs which look as follows:

```
2020-05-17T21:01:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-17T21:01:23.528711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=wsb-project.herokuapp.com request_id=4ea57e57-b230-4d49-99d6-f5f17856b589 fwd="85.221.138.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T21:01:23.897006+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wsb-project.herokuapp.com request_id=59fc1c4d-330c-4084-8e9e-1a3d7d8ed292 fwd="85.221.138.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T21:09:45.484945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=wsb-project.herokuapp.com request_id=f1cd7d3d-8781-49b8-80e0-278ca06139ce fwd="85.221.138.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T21:09:45.885362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=wsb-project.herokuapp.com request_id=64c1d78c-8e75-47d0-b748-9ffbf239c545 fwd="85.221.138.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Heroku ps tells me that no dynos are on my app.
I tried [this tutorial:](http://vibhurishi.blogspot.com/2013/02/heroku-error-h14-with-django.html)
and when scaling dynos I was informed that "couldn't find that process type(web)"
So I tried to clear and add the buildpacks again using [this link](https://help.heroku.com/W23OAFGK/why-am-i-seeing-couldn-t-find-that-process-type-when-trying-to-scale-dynos)

And still nothing works.
Thanks in advance in any of you know where I could find a solution as I am slowly running out of options here :)
Cheers.

Adding directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 17 14:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 16 14:22 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 18 19:09 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 bapti 197609     72 May 13 20:29 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 16 14:44 .idea/
-rw-r--r-- 1 bapti 197609 155648 May 17 14:18 db.sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609    652 Apr  1 14:16 manage.py*
-rw-r--r-- 1 bapti 197609     43 May 15 19:01 Procfile.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 14 22:25 python-getting-started/
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 15 17:46 register/
-rw-r--r-- 1 bapti 197609    301 May 16 11:11 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 16 13:31 restaurants/
-rw-r--r-- 1 bapti 197609     12 May 15 19:03 runtime.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 Apr 14 11:45 sent_emails/
drwxr-xr-x 1 bapti 197609      0 May 17 23:33 WSB_website/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is most likely the result of scaling your web dynos down to 0 dynos. To fix it, scale your web dynos to 1 or more dynos:

`heroku ps:scale web=1` or if it asks for an app, `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a wsb-project`

> The Procfile is always a simple text file that is named Procfile without a file extension. For example, Procfile.txt is not valid.

The Procfile must live in your app’s root (main) directory. It does not function if placed anywhere else.

The content of Procfiles can be set up as following,

```
web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: Hi,
Everytime I try to scale my web dynos I have the message:
Couldn't find that process type (web)
So I assume there is something wrong with the setup somewhere but I can't put my finger on it

Comment: I believe something is wrong in your `Procfile` I have updated my answer see it.

Comment: Directory structure added as requested

Comment: Your Profile is named incorrectly, change it to `Procfile` not `Procfile.txt` (without any extension)

Comment: Changed my Procfile format from .txt to no extension and it worked fine to solve this error, thanks.